# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() using XAMPP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, postgresql, visual-studio-code, xampp

I have this problem when I try to run `connect.php` with this code:

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=books user=postgres password=123 port=5434");
if($conn){
    echo "success";
}
```

I work with Visual Studio Code and I download the package postgreSQL. After that I restart the XAMPP and nothing happend. I remove semicolon in `php.ini` -> `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` but the same problem occurs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `pgsql.dll` if you want to use [`pg_*()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php) functions.

You enabled `php_pdo_pgsql.dll` which allows for connecting to PG DBs using the [PDO extension](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php).